# Как убрать ActionBar/TitleBar на своем layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Написал свое сообщение об ошибке используя свой layout. не могу избавится от полоски (ActionBar/TitleBar) в layout. Попытка сменить тему для layout к успеху не привела. Подскажите как?

---

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp"
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
tools:actionBarNavMode="standard"
tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="@string/server_data_error"
    android:textColor="#DDCE4F"
    android:textSize="27sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="129dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alarm_warning" />
```

---

Код вызова:

```
public void Press(View view) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        CustomDialofFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialofFragment ();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogFragment");        
    }
```

Код класса для окна:

```
public class CustomDialofFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

[image: Синяя полоса от которой хочу избавиться]

Comment: вот так уже понятнее что у вас происходит)) я обновил ответ, там в самом низу есть рабочий вариант, если что-то не получится пишите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например можно так:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

либо в стилях пропишите:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
```

самый простой способ:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

А там уже какой вам способ нравится такой и используйте :)

### UPDATE

У вас в xml есть строка:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

тут можно убрать бар:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

это будет на полный экран. Либо так:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

### UPDATE_2.0

Либо вот у меня есть диалог стили:

```
 <style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialog_back</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/down_from_top</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/up_from_bottom</item>
    </style>
```

тут убран бар но он на полный экран насколько я помню, уберите ненужные теги. И потом примените стиль вместо темы в xml макета.

### UPDATE_3.0

В вашем случае все делается так. У вас есть класс отвечающий за создание диалог фрагмента. Делаете override onCreate, и дальше там сетите стиль:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
    }
```

пример на котлине привел, но принцип понятен я думаю. И уберите из xml тему. Пример стиля есть выше, вам нужно будет только убрать или добавить в него то что вам нужно.

Comment: На ActivityMain он должен остаться, всплывающее сообщение должно быть без него.

Comment: Попытка сменить тему для layout к успеху не привела. - ответ на первый update

Comment: Update не помогли, диалог сделан на public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: public void Press(View view) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        CustomDialofFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialofFragment ();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogFragment");
    }  (Как в комментариях добавлять код нормально?)

Comment: getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: не распознает getDialog - предлагает добавить метод

Comment: Спасибо Andrew Goroshko.

Comment: Возможно еще придется в Manifest.xml добавить атрибут android:theme в целевую активити